# HP 6520 stops connecting to EnGenius ens202ext

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, printer, wireless-access-point

We have multiple EnGenius ens202ext AP around campus and I connect our HP6520 printer no problem, Also connect iPads to AirPrint to the printer. Everything worked fine for about an hour. Then the next time I connected the printers to the same AP it worked for about 5-10 minutes until it disconnected me from the AP and will not connect again. Every other device will still connect.

I tried to connect to another access point of the same model but different SSID about 300 feet from the previous one on a different network and still will not connect. I called HP with no help at all and also called EnGenius, also with was no help. I printed a report from the printer and it says everything passes except for filtering failed. So I tried enabling Mac filtering on the AP and it works fine now. My problem is that i need other users on this access point that I cant manually input their Mac address every time they connect.

Has anyone had something even remotely like this happen to them?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps anyone in this situation. I pretty much came to the conclusion that the MAC on the printer model itself is not compatible with the AP. I have tried several different printers (All the same make and model) and none of them worked on that access point for more than about 10 minutes on average. When applying MAC filtering and manually adding the MAC of the printer, they work fine.

In buying the same make but a different model printer, all printers other than that particular model work fine. From what I understand the first 6 digits in a MAC are company and model specific and the last 6 are randomly generated by the company. So it turns out that the Engenius 202EXT AP's do not like the first 6 digits in the MAC of the HP Photosmart 6520. If you have these AP's DO NOT buy these printers (if running them wireless).